# Icon layout help

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'm trying to replicate Apple's layout of its app icons. I'm having trouble using `<merge>` 
and `<include>` as it doesn't seem to show up in the app when I run it.

[image: Icon]

Here's the merge part:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/deleteContact"
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/personName"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="bottom|right"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:text="asdfasdf"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/personImage"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/icon"/>       

</merge>
```

The include is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<include layout="@layout/icon"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm putting those in a gridview here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:id="@+id/contactsGrid"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:numColumns="3"
              android:horizontalSpacing="3dip"
              android:verticalSpacing="3dip" />
```

We've managed to merge the image and the text so far using relativelayouts, however when we add the delete button, the whole icon itself can't be clicked anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are complicating things more than they may need to be. Try using a RelativeLayout as the parent view for the button, text, and imageview. For example take a look at the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/personImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/personName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/personImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/personImage"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/deleteContact"
    android:text="X"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/personImage"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/personImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You should actually be able to just use that in the GridView. You may want to replace the Button with an ImageButton that uses an actual image.

Comment: Thanks, but now the problem is that I can't click the icon itself. I can only click the button inside.

Comment: If you are using a ListAdapter to provide the items, you can set the onItemClickListener to the GridView. This will allow you to get a click for the entire item and not just the child views.